# Event handlers whose elements have a parent with a title attribute will not fire in some browsers

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

The HTML for this particular page is generated dynamically on load so I had to copy it from the console. The event only fails to fire on certain mobile browsers, Blackberry is especially prone to this issue.

When the input element is clicked the event handler correctly fires.

```
<div id="gatherer0" class="a">
  <div class="e" id="gatherer0header">text</div>
  <div class="f">
    <input type="button" value="val">
    <div class="d">
      <img src="img" class="b">
      <span id="gatherer0cost" class="c">text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the input element is clicked the event handler will not fire. The only difference between this and the above example is the title attribute.

```
<div id="upgrade0" class="a" title="Description">
  <div class="e" id="upgrade0header">text</div>
  <div class="f">
    <input type="button" value="val">
    <div class="d">
      <img src="img" class="b">
      <span id="upgrade0cost" class="c">text</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

An identical method is used to add event listeners to either button

```
storeItemButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    game.purchase(id);
    game.update();
}, false);
```

I have searched for all sorts of solutions and found nothing. Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the same identifier for multiple elements.

```
<div id="id" class="a">
<div class="e" id="id">text</div>
<span id="id" class="c">text</span>
```

Also avoid the keywords as the identifier `id="id"`

Comment: I should have specified. I removed all specific references to elements as they were not relevant to the question. I'll amend the post to clear up any confusion.